# How to store range to variant without losing format

Tags: excel, vba

The below code stores the numbers without the number format. How to store the value the number format stored in the price variable?

[image]

```
Sub StoreRangeToArray()
  Dim Price
  Price = Range("A2:A4")
  Range("B2:B4") = Price
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need a second Variant, or an Object.

Comment: @braX: Do you mean to store the number formats in second variant?

Comment: Right. a Variant can only hold a value. If you need more than that, you would so something like save it into an object variable instead.

Comment: **Why** do you want to store the number format? What are you doing with the data?

Comment: @Rory: As my question, I want to store the number in a variant without losing its format. The responders gave workaround like storing number format in a separate variable.

Comment: That is **what** you want to do, not **why** you need it. ;)

Comment: @Rory: If I have the value with its format I don't have to format it again when I put it into another range. It will become less efficient when the data is in millions of rows.

Comment: But you will with the answer you have accepted, and you will have to do it cell by cell, which will be very slow. Are you doing any processing to the array before outputting it that would change its dimensions?

Comment: @Rory: Yes. You are right. Unaccepted the question

Comment: I think you need to clarify *in your question* the whole process involved here. There may not actually be a good alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative via built-in xml spreadsheet data**

I want to demonstrate a rather unknown and quick alternative using the [Range.Value property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value)

This property enables to get values plus style information in **one go** via

- `Price = src.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)`

or abbreviated via

- `Price = src.Value(11)`

where `src` represents a defined range variable.

`Price` now includes any needed information about values and style formats in a well defined xml content (string) which you might want to analyze for other purposes, too.

```
Sub StoreRng2Arr()
'a) get source range
    Dim srcRng As Range: Set srcRng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A4")
'b) store data including formats to variable Price
    Dim Price As String
    Price = Store(srcRng)
    'Debug.Print Price           ' string output just for internal info
'c) write to target
    Dim tgtRng As Range: Set tgtRng = srcRng.Offset(0, 1)
    list tgtRng, Price
    'alternatively: tgtRng.Value(11) = Price
End Sub
```

```
Function Store(src As Range) As String
    Store = src.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)
End Function
```

```
Sub list(tgt As Range, ByVal xml As String)
    tgt.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet) = xml
End Sub
```

**Side notes, tl;dr**

A possible output in VB Editor's immediate window after  `Debug.Print Price` could be as follows and might be an interesting start for further analysis.

It might even help to explore some Excel pecularities like numeric precision, row and column evidence in xml using namespaces etc. - *fyi: disposing of some xml knowledge you might want to see several other posts of mine regarding xml spreadsheet analysis*.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s65">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0.00_ ;[Red]\-#,##0.00\ "/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Names>
  <NamedRange ss:Name="_xlpm.item" ss:RefersTo="=#NAME?" ss:Hidden="1"/>
  <NamedRange ss:Name="_xlpm.items" ss:RefersTo="=#NAME?" ss:Hidden="1"/>
  <NamedRange ss:Name="_xlpm.str" ss:RefersTo="=#NAME?" ss:Hidden="1"/>
 </Names>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="3"
   ss:DefaultColumnWidth="62.400000000000006" ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.4">
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="Number">2282.0500000000002</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="Number">564</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="Number">1539</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

**Caveat**

Note that *Assigning an array to a multi-* **area** *range is not properly supported.*

Comment: I did not know about `xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet` and it's pretty interesting. But in this context, not sure how can help. How can you easily access to a specific cell and get the info into variant type? Splitting text maybe?

Comment: imo this answer fully covers OP's question for storage of the source range's data including style in variable `Price` @Dhay wants to use for an eventual writing back.  - Yes, I wrote several posts for more special needs using xml techniques for getting or changing individual cell values/styles you might want to search for more information. The variant data field type is no alternative here as it doesn't store data Plus style info. *btw 'd up your post*

Answer (score 2):

Following @braX comment you could something like this:

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim dataArray As Variant
Dim formatArray As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set rng = Range("A1:A5")
dataArray = rng.Value
formatArray = dataArray 'so both of them will have same structure

'loop trough range to get formats
For i = 1 To 5 Step 1
    formatArray(i, 1) = Range("A" & i).NumberFormatLocal 'or choose just NumberFormat
Next i

'print value (no format) and number format
For i = LBound(dataArray) To UBound(dataArray) Step 1
    Debug.Print dataArray(i, 1), formatArray(i, 1)
Next i


Erase dataArray
Erase formatArray

End Sub
```

Notice I'm using `NumberFormatLocal` just because I think it's easier but you can use NumberFormat too.

The output I get is this:

[image]

Notice the value `0,25` in the cell A4 is seen as `06:00:00` because it's formatted using `hh:mm:ss`.

**UPDATE:** If you want to use just a single array:

```
Sub test_2()

Dim vArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A5")

ReDim vArray(1 To rng.Rows.Count, 1 To 2)

'loop trough range and take all into single array: column index 1 = data, column index 2 = numberformat

For i = 1 To 5 Step 1
    vArray(i, 1) = Range("A" & i).Value
    vArray(i, 2) = Range("A" & i).NumberFormat 'or numberformatlocal if you wish
Next i

'print all
For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray) Step 1
    Debug.Print vArray(i, 1), vArray(i, 2)
Next i

'clean variables
Set rng = Nothing
Erase vArray

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: can you copy a range with formula and formatted such as bold with interior color into another sheet but paste just the values with its formatting?

Comment: @k1dr0ck Yes, you can. But OP asked about number format and values, not about cell format. Number format would be showing the value as a date,  how many decimals, and stuff like that. Cell format is font color, cell color and stuff like that.

Comment: i was just asking out of curiosity, how do you store a cell format is it like this? `vArray(i, 2) = Range("A" & i).Interior.Color` then use like in another sheet `Range("B" & i).Interior.Color=vArray(i, 2)`

Comment: @k1dr0ck Not tested buy probably yes. Remember a `Variant` type can hold any type of data so yes, it would work.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns: Can we do this without looping aka in one line?

Comment: @Dhay As far as I know, nope. I've tried `arrayFormat = Range("A1:A5").NumberFormat` but it does not work as expected. So you are forced to loop **or** copy the cell range and paste the whole format somewhere else.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns There is a - rather unknown - way which avoids looping via built-in xml spreadsheet info, see my post below :+)